# GCP Console - prompt to refresh the page

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Several of GCP accounts I use display a message after logging in:

> Refresh the page?
>   Now that you’ve upgraded, we need to refresh the page so you can take advantage of the new capabilities of your account. Do you want to refresh the page now, or do it yourself later?

Does anyone else see similar message? Wonder what kind of upgrade it relates to, I don't remember making any changes to the account recently. Hitting `OK, refresh now` doesn't produce any visible changes. Also it seems there is no way of making this message disappear - acknowledging or rejecting will still trigger a popup on next login.
[popup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZdxS.png)

Comment: are your projects shared with other developers/engineers?

Comment: yes, I do have other developers as Project Editors

Comment: Why does the implementation of a vendor's web browser interface matter? Press the Refresh button and be done. You have no control over this other than maybe curiosity. In that case you will need to direct your question at a Google Cloud Console GUI developer at Google and not on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about programming, and is likely best addressed by Google support or filing an issue with google.

Comment: is stackoverflow only about programming? btw it's not very easy to contact GCP support on lower tier plans
@JohnHanley it's not vendor's browser interface, rather an unknown popup that I see repeatedly (been using GCP for years). Confirming Refresh doesn't do anything, as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Officially, Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. To quote: "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.". Sometimes reading the documentation helps: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Now given my official comment on Stackoverflow, that is not always the case for a lot of questions. However, Stackoverflow is not technical support for a vendor. Just because you cannot receive support from that vendor does not move that responsibility to Stackoverflow.

Comment: When posting a question on Stackoverflow remember that "volunteers" answer it. Your question should have benefit to the community and not to only service your needs.

Comment: To help you with your question. Most likely something is cached in your browser. Clear the browsers cache and cookies and then do a full page reload (CTRL F5). Next, are you using Chrome? As you can imagine, Google will do more testing on their own browser. I have seen oddball issues here and there with other browsers (Edge/Firefox) but these tend to get fixed quickly.

Comment: @JohnHanley next time another developer faces similar issue and will highlight text/right click/search Google for "X", this thread might help him/her.

Comment: Which thread part? I have empathy for people that get stuck trying to solve problems and cannot find good information (or find too much junk).

Comment: @JohnHanley answer by Debdut below. Popup seems to happen on projects where I've added a specific developer, who included his SSH keys to connect.

Comment: Added his SSH keys to what and how? This indicates a problem and not a solution. Are you sharing Google Identities across users? Are more than one person using the same account to login to a local computer (where SSH keys are stored)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the developers/engineers the project is shared with are making some changes. Well as per my observation, whenever one makes a change in GCP, it automatically gets reloaded or the necessary changes take place in background, but when others are working at same project at the same time, then if one user makes any changes in a shared access resource, then other users might need to reload the site for the necessary changes to take place.
I would highly suggest you contact other developers/engineers you are sharing the project with to check if they made changes in the project or not.
Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: I think this is it. Recently a new developer was included in the project and added his SSH keys.

Comment: @farmlancer glad I could help :)